# A Minimum Ordering Requirement

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, relaxed-atomics

Let `x` and `y` be two different variables of type `std::atomic<int>` and assume that the current value of both of them is `1`. What is *a most relaxed* set of ordering requirements so the the following code generates some output? (i.e., what should be used for `order1` ... `order4`?)

```
// Thread 1
x.store(0, order1);       // A
if(0 == y.load(order2))   // B
  std::cout << '1';       // C
// Thread 2
y.store(0, order3);       // E
if(0 == x.load(order4))   // F
  std::cout << '2';       // G
```

Comment: unclear. There is no x and y in your code. What is w ? What is s ?

Comment: `some output` - any output at all? That means that you want one of points `C` or `G` or both points `C` and `G` to execute?

Comment: By `some output`, I mean `1` or `2` (or both, in any order) in the output.

Comment: I don't think there's any combination of ordering requirements that could guarantee that the program outputs anything.

Comment: I think sequentially consistent ordering should guarantee `some output`. Also `relaxed` or `acquire_rel` or `acquire_consume` won't guarantee `some output`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sequential consistency on all operations.

Release/acquire does not actually impose any ordering here, since there is no store before the release-store or load after the acquire-load, which would be ordered by it.

Relaxed memory ordering on any of the stores, e.g. `x.store` could cause the stores to become visible in different orders in the two threads. It then does not violate the sequential ordering of the remaining operations to have the relaxed store be visible after the load in the other thread, while the other store still is ordered after its corresponding load in the sequentially consistent total order.

With sequential ordering on all operations output is guaranteed, because there must be a total order of the sequential operations observed the same way in all threads. This order must be consistent with the sequencing order in the threads, i.e. `x.store < y.load` and `y.store < x.load`. The only possibilities are:

```
x.store < y.load  < y.store < x.load
x.store < y.store < x.load  < y.load
x.store < y.store < y.load  < x.load

y.store < x.load  < x.store < y.load
y.store < x.store < y.load  < x.load
y.store < x.store < x.load  < y.load
```

All of which observe for one of the variables a load after the store, triggering one of the `cout` statements.

If e.g. `x.store` is not `memory_order_seq_cst`, then, while it still needs to be sequenced before `y.load` in thread 1, it could become visible after `x.load` in thread 2.

`y.load < y.store < x.load` would then still satisfy the sequential consistency of the other operations and the modification order of `x` is trivially satisfied anyway.

Comment: You said, "This order must be consistent with the sequencing order in the threads". But according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering "The single total order might not be consistent with happens-before. This allows more efficient implementation of  ...". Am I missing something?

Comment: @Koosha That applies only to C++20. The changes are due to [p0668r5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0668r5.html), but I haven't read it yet. I don't think it will change anything about my answer.

Comment: @Koosha As you can see on the cppreference page, the requirement that the total order is consistent with the *happens-before* relation has been weakened to it being consistent with the *strongly happens-before* relation, but *sequenced-before* still implies *strongly happens-before* and I am only using the *sequenced-before* relation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`#StoreLoad` reordering can cause both loads to return the old value, so you need full sequential consistency on all 4 operations to prevent that.

Read up on store buffers to understand what causes this type of reordering.

Answer (score -1):

Two simple rules:

- as a first action after start of parallelism (start of threads), a release fence or operation doesn't have anything to make visible (in other threads), so nothing is "released" and the release is useless (everything was previously visible and is equally visible by threads started at the same time);
- as a last action before end of parallelism (end of threads), an acquire fence or operation doesn't have anything to make visible (in that thread) that wouldn't be visible in the common parent thread

Here you have:

> ```
> x.store(0, order1);       // A
> if(0 == y.load(order2))   // B
> ```

- a store at the start
- a load at the end

so neither acquire nor release semantic can make *any* difference.